# Set up Windows Defender to automatically scan as needed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

Is there a way to set up Windows Defender (in Windows 10) so that it performs its periodical scans and updates in the background without prompting user or demanding that a window remain open on the Desktop? My case involves a computer that remains off for a week or more once in a while...

Comment: Windows Defender has done what you ask since the day it was created. I'm not sure what popups you're talking about, but maybe you have malware. Send a screenshot. The only message I get from Windows Defender on windows 10 is a gentle notification in the lower right hand corner telling me my last scan didn't find any malware. You're not one who has tried to disable automatic windows updates have you?

Comment: I turn on my computer after some days of no use. Windows Defender pops notifications that I must take "recommended actions". I open, it says I must perform a Scan. I click "perform a scan", it starts. If I close that window, that scan is interrupted, the notification returns. If I do everything it wants from me, it gets happy and stops bothering me. Until I leave computer another week or so without use. My configurations are all "system recommended". All I want is it scans and updates whenever it wants without hassling me.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are leaving the computer off for so long. My computers stay on all the time, but even the ones I don't leave on all the time I haven't seen that on. But, if you don't let your system update and run regularly, then Windows Defender will need maintenance. It gets its updates at the same time Windows updates. I'll check it out a little later when I'm home.

Comment: That's your problem: if a system runs continuously, it will do exactly as you want (as @Appleoddity implies). However, if it is turned off for a period and a scan schedule is missed, then the self-monitoring will detect that there isn't a sufficiently recent scan, and prompt you to do it. All you can do is to ignore the prompt and wait for the next scheduled scan, but you may be prompted again before then.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It is only a pity that it demands a window to remain open after I command the scan...